# Mirror Modifier Issues - Asymmetry

Tags: modifiers, mirror

world,

I have been playing with Blender 2.8.1 for a couple of months and recently keep running into the same issue with a mirror modifier.

When I apply the modifier the mirrored object is way off-centre, like this:

[image]

I am able to solve the issue by simply joining the asset I want to mirror and another asset which already has a mirror modifier attached, however this adds the material from the latter object to the object I'm trying to mirror which is undesirable.

Any techniques to help me create a perfect mirror when I'm working with multiple assets will be much appreciated if provided.

Comment: in the mirror modifier -> with the eye dropper select the middle body part

Answer (score 1):

By default the mirror modifier will choose its mirroring axes depending on the object's origin, not the world origin.

The origin of each object is marked by a yellow dot when it is selected. As you can see, your tooth's yellow dot is a little bit to the left of it, so logically the mirror modifier creates a copy with a symmetry relative to its that.

If you want to create a mirror with a symmetry to the world origin, you have to select in the "Mirror object" field of the mirror modifier **either**:

- An object which you know has their origin in the world origin 0, 0, 0
- Create a new empty object, and keep it at the origin point
- Make sure your 3D cursor is at the origin with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and while your object is selected, right click > Set Origin > To 3D Cursor

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding the middle body part as the mirror object parameter. Thanks.